# Amplify and Goddady forwarding to www subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, next.js, aws-amplify

Hello people I have an issue regarding Amplify and Godaddy, hosting a next.js site.

I'll explain the issue in list so I don't write too much and be as clear as possible.

1. I Have a GoDaddy account to which I have only delegated access to domains
2. I have deployed a next.js site (using SSR) on amplify
3. Eventually, I'll need to add the root domain to Goddady, but the issue is that amplify needs to add the root domain in an `ANAME`, not a `CNAME` which GoDaddy does not support.
4. I forward the root domain, to a www **subdomain** like so: `https://www.example.com`
5. When I access my browser my site, for example: `example.com` (without the www or any protocol) it redirects me perfectly to my website.

### The problem

If I go to my site like this: https://example.com, it loads nothing and sends a `PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR`. I can only access my site with: `example.com` or `www.example.com`.
And this issue is because, on amplify, when I set the domains, I'm setting the `www.example.com` with the actual branch code. Since I cannot add an `ANAME` to GoDaddy because `ANAME`'s are not supported, the root domain has to be disabled like so:
[image]

### Possible solutions?

I cannot have access to all the products of GoDaddy and change nameservers.

I did add a 301 forwarding in GoDaddy from the root domain to the www subdomain. But still, accessing `https://example.com` does NOT redirect to the `www.example.com` one.

Is using Nginx a solution? or probably a raw .htaccess file?
I mean, I don't care if the domain goes to a `www`, I just need it to redirect it.

PD:
On amplify I have my redirections as well:
[image]

I'll appreciate a lot your help, It's been 3 days and nothing.

Comment: Yeah, at the end I requested access to change the NameServers and do the redirect from there. It took me like a month to solve it. Also, since this was a project from a client and it was some time ago I really forgot the steps. But you need to chnage the name servers.